# I'm getting a "missing $ inserted" error even though it's plaintext. What did I do wrong?

Tags: math-mode, errors

Here is the text that generates the error.

> SaaS is een afkorting voor ``Software as a Service". Dit houdt in dat de klant tegen een doorlopende vergoeding online gebruik kan maken van de software die geleverd wordt `\cite{34}`. Naast het aanbieden van standaardpakketten gaat Top ook in gesprek met de klanten en ontwikkelen de pakketten verder op de wensen van de klant.

**Update:**

The error was generated by the url in the bib entry. This was fixed by adding the url package.

The bib entry:

```
@misc{34,

author={Gil, Paul},
title={What Is 'SaaS' (Software as a Service)?},
url={http://netforbeginners.about.com/od/s/f/what_is_SaaS_software_as_a_service.htm},
journal={About.com Tech}
```

Comment: Welcome, we need a bit more information. What is the actual error message?

Comment: Probably you have an underscore character in the bib entry `34`

Comment: @percusse the bib is: @misc{34,
author={Gil, Paul},
title={What Is 'SaaS' (Software as a Service)?},
url={http://netforbeginners.about.com/od/s/f/what_is_SaaS_software_as_a_service.htm},
journal={About.com Tech}

Comment: Can you temporarily remove the `url` field of that entry and try again ?

Comment: @percusse I have removed it and it removed the error. Thanks

Comment: Thanks all. Due to @percusse his perception I found out I could fix it by adding the url package

Comment: @Daniël -- as it's stated now, this question is a candidate for being closed as "off topic for lack of information".  if you could add the bib entry that triggered the error, then it would still be a candidate for closure, but this time as a duplicate, which is much more helpful to future visitors to this site.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I edited the description of the question. Is this what you mentioned I should do? This was my first post, so I am sorry if I made a mistake.

Comment: @Daniël -- that's perfect.  i edited it further to "highlight" the code.  you can do that in future questions by mousing over the code block, then clicking on the `{}` icon above the edit window.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by "user error", namely an underscore character in the ulr field.